# Function 'SaveSettings' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.

Tags: vb.net

I have changed my vb program and try to run this and I always get this warnings.  I tried most of the codes but I dont know what am I doing wrong..

```
Public Class clsSettings
        Shared Function SaveSettings()
            Try
                My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "sourcepath", frmMain.txtSourcePath.Text)
                My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "convertedpath", frmMain.txtConvertedPath.Text)
                My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "countrycode", frmMain.txtCountryCode.Text)
            If frmMain.AutoRun.Checked = True Then
                    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "autorun", "1")
                Else
                    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "autorun", "0")

                If My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "autorun", "") = 1 Then
                    frmMain.AutoRun.Checked = True
                Else
                    frmMain.AutoRun.Checked = False
                End If
              MessageBox.Show("Settings saved successfully", "Aquila Settings", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Aquila could not save settings", "Aquila Settings", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

 Return False
    End Try
        End Function
```

Comment: Please put Option Strict On at the top of your code file or in the project's properties.  Your Function declaration doesn't specify a return type.

Answer (score 1):

That warning is pretty straightforward: your function is only providing a return value if an exception is caught. With `Option Strict Off`, `Nothing` is assumed as the default return value for your function as it stands (you did not specify a return type, so `Object` is assumed), so you actually never return `True` for a "successful" save. Add a `Return` at the end of the function:

```
' Add a return type to the function...
Shared Function SaveSettings() As Boolean
    Try
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "sourcepath", frmMain.txtSourcePath.Text)
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "convertedpath", frmMain.txtConvertedPath.Text)
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "countrycode", frmMain.txtCountryCode.Text)
    If frmMain.AutoRun.Checked = True Then
            My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "autorun", "1")
        Else
            My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "autorun", "0")

        If My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ANPR International\Aquila Image Bridge\", "autorun", "") = 1 Then
            frmMain.AutoRun.Checked = True
        Else
            frmMain.AutoRun.Checked = False
        End If
      MessageBox.Show("Settings saved successfully", "Aquila Settings", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Aquila could not save settings", "Aquila Settings", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Return False
    End Try

    ' Add Return at the end of the function here
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

return something in each situation. Like

```
if ---
    return true    
else

  if --
      return true
  else
      return false
  end if

end if
```

In your code, there are few situation where nothing returning.